# Is it possible to use spatial function to retrieve non-spatial data?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm using PostGIS  in postgresql.I wish to calculate points within the radius from particular geocode.For that i have created a table with spatial column geocode having datatype as geometry and inserted some values using following query.

```
INSERT INTO aspatial_address( addressline,country,geocode)
  VALUES ('','', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(14.083333 70.583333)', 4326));
```

As geocode having geometry datatype inserted values of geocode are stored in hex format.Ex. for "POINT(10,19.1)" it stores '010100000000000000000024409A99999999193340' as geocode.

I can retrieve these value in normal geocode format using **ST_AsText(geocode)geocode** function using :

```
select addressid,ST_AsText(geocode)geocode from aspatial_address as A where ST_Point_Inside_Circle(a.geocode,14.083333,19.583333,7)
```

Till everything is fine.

Now i wish to select geocode values from non-spatial postgres tables. 
for that i have tried same query but their in incompatibility between datatype of geocode.As spatial have geometry datatype and non-spatial have character varying datatype it gives error.Can i convert datatype through query using any function or i have to change query?

Comment: I dont fully understand the question. You have a non-spatial database, where you store the WKB representation of a point in a column with type varchar? If thats the case, you can use the function ST_PointFromWKB http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_PointFromWKB.html on the WKB value to get a geometry instance.

Comment: thanks @til_b for reply.I have non-spatial db and i wish to use inbuilt function of postgis on that db.is it possible? In the Starting part of question i have tried query on sample spatial table but actually i wish to use it on non-spatial

Comment: Please show the second (non-spatial) query. The question isn't very clear.

Comment: @ John Barça thanks for reply.my question is - how can i use non-spatial query to retrieve points from circle within particular radius? i have updated my title.Please take a look

Comment: The purpose of spatial queries is to exploit the spatial index. While it is possible to store WKT or WKB in a table and use it in spatial query constraints, this will be *very* inefficient and unsuitable for all but trivial implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your structure is someting like this

```
table A (
  id int,
  location varchar(MAX)
)
```

and the data

```
insert into A VALUES(1, '010100000000000000000024409A99999999193340')
```

then you can (bearing in mind the huge performance penalty mentioned by @Vince ) query your database using something like

```
select * from A where ST_Point_Inside_Circle(ST_PointFromWKB(A.location),14.083333,19.583333,7)
```

(all code untested)